# Remove Single Quotes From All Cells in a DataTable - Creating New Table - Using LINQ in Vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a table with many values inside of it that might have single quotes around them.  I need to create a duplicate table without those single quotes.  I can't modify the original table as I need to use it, 'as-is' later.

I've done this with a table.Clone and using a foreach to loop through the rows and columns removing single quotes as I need and then putting that new row into the new table.  It works and it's straight forward.....but

I'd like to do the same thing using LINQ.  This was my attempt....

```
        Dim myResults = From myRow In dtTable _
                    From myItem In myRow.ItemArray _
                    Where TypeOf myItem Is String AndAlso _
                    myItem.ToString.StartsWith("'"c) AndAlso _
                    myItem.ToString.EndsWith("'"c)
```

As you can see - I didn't get very far.  I had trouble finding examples that weren't looking at a specific column in the DataRow.  It looks like my code does pull back all the matching results - but I'm at a lose for how I can create a duplicate table/modify the values?

EDIT - I've started a bounty for this in the hopes that someone can provide a solution.  The only requirement is to not using a For Each; as I already know how to do that.  I've gotten closer - but I still can't seem to create a new row or a new table.

My new approach hits a dead-end when I try to do this:

```
Dim MyNewRow As New Data.DataRow With {.ItemArray = myRemovedQuotes.ToArray}
```

The Error message I get says, "Error    1   'System.Data.DataRow.Protected Friend Sub New(builder As System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected Friend'."

Comment: Please tell me you're not doing this in an effort to prevent sql injection!  It's just the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Nah - none of this will passed into an SQL string.

Comment: I posted an answer in C#, but deleted it seeing the VB.NET tag; the problem is converting the object[] while keeping each row separate; I used Array.ConvertAll in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really *must* use LINQ (as a learning exercise, perhaps), then maybe something like below (as C#; my VB is nowhere near up to translating it, I'm afraid):

```
        DataTable clone = original.Clone();
        string t;
        var qry = from DataRow row in original.Rows
                  let arr = row.ItemArray
                  select Array.ConvertAll(arr, s =>
                      (t = s as string) != null
                      && t.StartsWith("\'")
                      && t.EndsWith("\'") ? t.Trim('\'') : s);
        foreach (object[] arr in qry) {
            clone.Rows.Add(arr);
        }
```

The problem is that the `ItemArray` needs to be expanded while retaining the separate rows (so `SelectMany` isn't an option); `Array.ConvertAll` seems the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Is your table generated locally (ie within the app) or coming from a database - if from the database I would be inclined to write a view that strips the single quotes before they  reach your app.