# How to replace double quotes of all rows of DataTable using Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How to replace double quotes of all rows of DataTable using Linq in C#?

I tried below but I need more optimized code for same purpose

```
int columnIndex = 0;
dtExcelData.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
foreach (DataColumn excelSheetColumns in dtExcelData.Columns)
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows)
    {
        dtExcelData.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex] = dtExcelData.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
        rowIndex++;
    }
    columnIndex++;
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: `I need more optimized code for the same purpose` Do you want to optimize performance or clean code (shorter conde)?

Comment: I need achieve result with very less code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Single Quotes From All Cells in a DataTable - Creating New Table - Using LINQ in Vb.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711616/remove-single-quotes-from-all-cells-in-a-datatable-creating-new-table-using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of DataRow.ItemArray. For example

```
foreach(var row in dtExcelData.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    row.ItemArray = row.ItemArray.Select(x=>x.ToString().Replace("\"","")).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should

- be aware you remove the first row, if you write results back to your data store you will lose this row.
- ask yourself why you iterare over Columns and rows if you never use the objects. Why don't you simply use a for loop over rowIndex and columnIndex.
- think about only processing data fields that really are a string.ToString() turns everything into a string, then you overwrite any kind of data field type with a string. Better test for "is String" and then cast the field into (String).
- think about getting every row, then process every column in this row. This could be faster to execute, but even if it isn't then still is more understandable (at least to me).

Answer (score 0):

I have added code here because code is better other than URL, You can try this below code:

That is already mentioned in below URL

[Remove Single Quotes From All Cells in a DataTable - Creating New Table - Using LINQ in Vb.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711616/remove-single-quotes-from-all-cells-in-a-datatable-creating-new-table-using)

```
 dtExcelData.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
 DataTable clone = dtExcelData.Clone();
        string t;
        var qry = from DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows
                  let arr = row.ItemArray
                  select Array.ConvertAll(arr, s =>
                      (t = s as string) != null
                      && t.StartsWith("\"")
                      && t.EndsWith("\"") ? t.Trim('\"') : s);
        foreach (object[] arr in qry)
        {
            clone.Rows.Add(arr);
        }
```

Comment: I want to write back data to dtExcelData object itself instead of creating new DataTable  object using clone.